# Responsive drop down menu toggle 'menu' 'close' text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive dropdown menu, that kicks in at a certain breakpoint. I have text saying 'Menu'. On click this opens the nav and clicking again it closes the nav. How can I change the text, when the menu is opened, to 'Close'? The javascript also on click adds a class to the `header` to fix it in the window. And to stop the `body` from scrolling behind the `header` it adds a class to the body to give the `body` a `height` of `0`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.querySelector("nav");
  element.classList.toggle("show-nav");
  var element = document.querySelector("header");
  element.classList.toggle("show-nav");
  var element = document.querySelector("body");
  element.classList.toggle("show-nav");
}
```

```css
.open-menu {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.open-menu:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

nav {
  display: none;
}

nav.show-nav {
  display: block;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 6.3rem);
}

header.show-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body.show-nav {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="open-menu"><span onclick="myFunction()">Menu</span></div>
  <nav>...</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `CSS` to do the heavy lifting (positioning, text changes etc...) and only use `JS` to toggle the `.show-nav` class.

Also, there is no need to apply the class for the `header` and `nav` as you may simply add it to the body and use `CSS` to only apply the necessary styles for the `header` and `nav` only when the `body` has the `.show-nav` class applied.

And for the text change, the trick is to use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to show the text and change that text with `CSS` when the `.show-nav` class is applied on the `body` element.

Also I made some changes to make things clearer and more accessible in terms of `HTML`. And here's a live demo along with some helpful comments:

```js
/** select the button that open the NAV */
const menuOpener = document.querySelector('.open-menu');

/** apply a click event handler that simply toggles the ".show-nav" class from the body */
menuOpener.addEventListener('click', () => document.body.classList.toggle('show-nav'));
```

```css
.open-menu {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}


/** we'll use the after pseudo-element to show the button's text. By default the text is "Menu" */
.open-menu:after {
  content: "Menu";
}

nav {
  display: none;
}

body.show-nav {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/** As we'll only apply the "show-nav" class to the body, we can use the selector "body.show-nav ..." to select the wanted elements when the body has the ".show-nav" class applied */


/** When the body has the ".show-nav" class, we'll change the button's text to "Close" */
body.show-nav .open-menu:after {
  content: "Close"
}


/** the NAV styles when the body has the ".show-nav" class applied */

body.show-nav nav {
  display: block;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 6.3rem);
}


/** the HEADER styles when the body has the ".show-nav" class applied */
body.show-nav header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- A button is used instead of a DIV to make thiongs more accessible for keyboards and more logical. Also, that button will not have any text as the text will be added and changed by the CSS -->
  <!-- The aria-label is just to help assistive technologies to know and pronounce the button's text -->
  <button class="open-menu" aria-label="Menu"></button>
  <nav>my nav items here...</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: That looks brilliant. I'll implement it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @user2991837 You're welcome! Glad I managed to help. Feel free to ask for further assistance when needed.

Comment: Two questions. Why suggest different JavaScript? Is there anything wrong with my original JS? Secondly, I've put the JS into the body between script tags just under the button code. It works, but is this the best place for it?

Comment: @user2991837 1) If you have something that can be done using `CSS`, avoid implementing it with `JS` as it will make things slower especially on larger projects. 2) Putting the `JS` at the end of the page just before the `body`'s closing tag ensures that any referenced element in the code are found in the page. Anyway, there are more details than that, you may take a look at how browsers parse and deal with a web page.